# Creating a Polarion LiveDoc containing a Test Run

Tags: polarion

I was wondering if it would be possible to create a LiveDoc Test Report, which would allow to add the results of a test run inside a Collection, for instance.

A LiveReport is very limited in this sense: it can only be exported in PDF, without having an actual document in Polarion. Thanks!